# Backing up code on an FTP server

Tags: backup, git

I have a web hosting service, I want to store my code on it. 
I was thinking perhaps opening a Git repo for the entire dev/ directory 
and somehow in the Git hooks make it upload only the files that have been 
changed to the server (I can't install git on the web hosting site). 
Is there something similar? like an already git-hook for that? 
Perhaps a smarter solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of our friends at Stack Overflow [wanted a tool to upload their `git`-hosted web application to their production server via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950107/git-push-into-production-ftp), and it turns out two of the tools one user recommended support incremental backup:

> [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) by René Moser is a simple
>   shell script for doing FTP the Git
>   way. Use git-ftp.sh to upload only the
>   Git tracked files to a FTP server,
>   which have changed since the last
>   upload. This saves time and bandwith.
>   Even if you play with different
>   branches, git-ftp.sh knows which files
>   are different. No ordinary FTP client
>   can do that.
>
> [git-ftp](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp) by Edward Z. Yang is a
>   simple script written in python for
>   uploading files in a Git repository
>   via FTP, only transferring new files
>   and removing old files.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that git is already installed. If you have interactive SSH access, be sure to check for it – this would work much faster than a 'dumb' FTP transport.

But if only FTP is available:

```
git remote add webhost ftps://asaf@webhost.tld/code.git
```